# PyQGIS: Load selected style categories with loadNamedStyle()

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3

I would like to load a specific category of the default style of a layer. Layer and style are stored in a Postgres database.

The `loadDefaultStyle` function doesn't take arguments, so I tried this from Python Console:

```
styles = layer.listStylesInDatabase()
layer.loadNamedStyle(styles[2][0], QgsMapLayer.Labeling)
```

I also tried variations with named parameter, but can't get it to work. It should be possible according to [docs](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsMapLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsMapLayer.loadNamedStyle)

Answer (score 2):

Here a standalone solution where we first list styles, then make a dict to match style id to style layer name. Then, we retrieve the qgis qml style as a string. We use it in a `QgsMapLayerStyle`, load the qml to the layer and then refresh the canvas. Done! (PS: tested before answering ;) )

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()

styles = layer.listStylesInDatabase()
namedStylesToId = dict(zip(styles[2], styles[1]))
my_style_name = 'mydemo1'
qml_content, _ = layer.getStyleFromDatabase(namedStylesToId.get(my_style_name))
lStyle = QgsMapLayerStyle(qml_content)

lStyle.writeToLayer(layer)
iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers()
```